# Changing image on select onchange

Tags: javascript

I want to change image on selection. I will explain how the whole thing is working. Actually first I am changing an image based on selected color. I have done that part with help of the community. Now I want to change the image based on the selection. If yes then load the image of the same color but with color.

This is what I have tried but its not working :(

```js
    function collarChange(clickedOption) {
        if (clickedOption.value == "Yes")
        {
            if ( document.getElementById("libaasImage").src == "images/black.png" )
            {
                document.getElementById("libaasImage").src = "images/black-collar.png";
            }
        }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 colourWhite" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 colourBlack" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 colourGold" onclick="ChangeLibaas(this)"></div>

<select onchange="collarChange(this)">
    <option value="select">Select..</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Silly question - does this page also have an `<img>` element with an id of "libaasImage"?

Comment: Try to replace `images/black.png` with `/images/black.png`

Comment: @EatPeanutButter yes. Updated the question

Comment: Your inner conditional is trying to match a src that doesn't exist: `images/black.png` <> `images/white.png`  Thus it is evaluating as false, and nothing happens.

Comment: "Is not working" is not a useful description.  What happens? Do you have errors? Does it run, but changing the select doesn't update the image? Have you used your developer console to step through the code - does the event trigger?

Comment: You didn't see `/` before the source string in the tip.

Comment: @cale_b I dont get any errors. Changing the select doesn't update the image.

Comment: Getting the `src` of an image, in some browsers, returns the absolute URL to the image, rather than the relative one. You might need to use `indexOf` on the `src`. Also, your parameter name, `clickedOption`, is not technically correct. You're actually passing the `select` element by using `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle that may help you craft your code.  Two things to notice:
1) I passed the event into your `collarChange` function to access the selected value.
2) I changed your `if` statement to check the `indexOf`.

https://jsfiddle.net/x0hrgj84/

HTML:

```
<select onchange="collarChange(event)">
    <option value="select">Select..</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<img src="images/black.png" id="libaasImage">
```

Javascript:

```
collarChange = function (event) {
  if (event.target.value == "Yes")
  {
    if ( document.getElementById("libaasImage").src.indexOf("images/black.png") != -1 )
    {
      document.getElementById("libaasImage").src = "images/black-collar.png";
    }
  }
}
```